# configure Apache Hive local multi users or in Spark standalone without Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hive

We run Apache Spark stand alone for teaching purposes on Fedora 27. I have it configured with MySQL for the metastore_db.

I am trying to follow [this tip running Hive in local mode](http://hadoop-pig-hive-thejas.blogspot.com/2013/04/running-hive-in-local-mode.html), so running the export command:
 `export  HIVE_OPTS='-hiveconf mapred.job.tracker=local -hiveconf fs.default.name=file:///tmp -hiveconf hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=file:///tmp/warehouse'` before starting `hive`. [Another blog suggested](http://whatsbuzzingapachehive.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-install-and-run-apache-hive-in.html) this command:

```
export HIVE_OPTS='-hiveconf mapred.job.tracker=local -hiveconf fs.default.name=file:///tmp -hiveconf hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=file:///tmp/warehouse -hiveconf javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/tmp/metastore_db;create=true'
```

So I ran `chmod 777 /tmp/warehouse` but won't any subsequent users just rewrite over everything in this local file database? Is there a better way to achieve this? Whenever I try to use Hive within Spark or without any export of a local file database I get the `localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;` errors, i.e. the port that Hadoop runs on. We're trying to do this without Hadoop for teaching purposes. Should each user just specify a different path to either `warehouse` or `databaseName`, perhaps in their home directory?

Comment: Spark only needs a running Hive metastore, it doesn't require a HiveServer installation, which would imply you needed Hadoop binaries available

Comment: Other option, just use the Hadoop minicluster or pseudo-distributed mode. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CLIMiniCluster.html

Comment: I'll consider mini cluster hadn't thought of that. If not, then would using the local file option with a different path work?

Comment: Would Hadoop mini cluster work with Hive? Are there any different configurations to keep in mind in the hive-site.xml file?

Comment: It should work. I personally have not tried, but putting the warehouse directory to an `hdfs://` path (which actually points at a local datanode directory) is the only specific property I can think of

Comment: Does Hadoop mini cluster work for concurrent users, i.e., 30 users?

Comment: It's meant for integration testing, not really multi-tenant work, but I don't see why not other than it bottlenecking on your local HDD and network